# Color each arc of sunburst based on size value

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am working with NVD3 to make a sunburst chart. I'm new to D3 in general so I'm using NVD3 to abstract some of the more complicated things away. Right now I am working with a simple example I got from the web, but am trying to color the nodes (arcs) based on the `size` attribute in the JSON. I know that NVD3 has the option to use a `color` function in the chart options so that's what I tried to use like so:

```
chart: {
      type: 'sunburstChart',
      height: 450,
      color: function(d) {
        if (d.size > 3000) {
          return "red";
        } else if (d.size <= 3000) {
          return "green";
        } else {
          return "gray";
        }
      },
      duration: 250
    }
```

But as you can see from the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vmg0pN?p=preview) I am working on that results in just gray, because it isn't actually getting a value from `d.size` (it's just undefined and I'm not sure why).

Using regular D3 which I am trying to avoid, I can get the desire result from this:

```
  var path = g.append("path")
               .attr("class","myArc")
               .attr("d", arc)
               .attr("name",function(d){return "path Arc name " + d.name;})
               .style("fill", function(d) {
                 if(d.size > 3000) {
                   return "green";
                 } else  if( d.size < 3000){
                   return "red";
                 } else {
                   return "gray";
                 }
                })
               .on("click", click)
               ... //etc
```

I had modified a regular D3 sunburst example to get that with the desired result:

[image]

I know the labels are jacked up but that isn't important here. I'd just like to get the same result as regular D3 but with the abstraction of NVD3. I haven't found any good examples that mention using the `color: function()` at all. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly use these javascript libraries from github distributions:

```
<script src="http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/bower_components/nvd3/build/nv.d3.js"></script>
<script src="http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/bower_components/angular-nvd3/dist/angular-nvd3.js"></script>
```

Chart options should be like this:

```
 $scope.options = {
    "chart": {
      "type": "sunburstChart",
      "height": 450,
      "duration": 250,
      "width": 600,
      "groupColorByParent": false,//you missed this
      color: function(d, i) {
        //search on all data if the name is present done to get the size from data
        var d2 = d3.selectAll("path").data().filter(function(d1) {
          return (d1.name == d)
        })[0];
        //now check the size
        if (d2.size > 3000) {
          return "red";
        } else if (d2.size <= 3000) {
          return "green";
        } else {
          return "gray";
        }
      },
      duration: 250
    }
  }
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/MDfwe6?p=preview)

Comment: Nice. This is very close to what I am looking for, but I am wondering why the values showing in the tooltips are now all just 1 instead of their true values. Also, any idea why there is a white arc in there now. There used to be one called `data` in its location. the same thing happens if you add more children nodes to some of the leafs (it creates white parents that aren't clickable) Like in this plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vmg0pN?p=preview). Notice the upper left side of the Sunburst and the same top right in your example.

Comment: Okay well the value issues was because the chart was set to count rather than size (sorry :) ) but I am still trying to find a solution to the white arcs appearing. The issue is definately coming from when I add the javascript libraries. The coloring doesn't work without them, but when I do add them the coloring works, but the white arcs appear.

Comment: The javascript libraries in cdn does not support `"groupColorByParent": false` only the libraries in the github dist wrk. regarding the white thing I dont know you can see the same issue in their demo  http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/sunburstChart

Comment: Huh, well that's interesting. Thanks though!!